# Hyphenation of Compound Adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives, compound-adjectives

Is this correct: Representation of a 4 to 9-node-quadrilateral element?

and this: which is the case of a multi-degree of freedom problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the hyphenation, I believe the first sentence should look like this:

> Representation of a 4-to-9-node quadrilateral element.

Here, **4-to-9-node** modifies **quadrilateral**, which in turn modifies **element**.

And:

> Which is the case of a multi-degree-of-freedom problem.

Because of the preposition **of**, **degree-of-freedom** modifies **problem**. However, **multi** also becomes part of that phrase.

With this one, if *single* were in front rather than **multi** it would be ambiguous unless the meaning were known in advance.

It could be a single instance of a degree-of-freedom problem:

> A single degree-of-freedom problem.

Or, it could be a degree-of-freedom problem that has only a single degree:

> A single-degree-of-freedom problem.

In order to understand which words are hyphenated, you need to understand the meaning of what's being expressed.

---

That not all elements that come before a final noun are hyphenated is explained in *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 7.87:

> Multiple hyphens are usually appropriate for such phrases as an *over-the-counter drug* or a *winner-take-all contest*. If, however, the compound modifier consists of an adjective that itself modifies a compound, additional hyphens may not be necessary. The expressions *late nineteenth-century literature* and *early twentieth-century growth* are clear without a second hyphen.

There are a lot of other guidelines when it comes to specific phrases. Although the general guidelines are clear, there are a *a lot* of exceptions. *Chicago* actually has a very long table of word and phrases along with hyphenations for them.